# Python regex alternative for join

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string `string = 'abcdefghi'` and I want the output as `'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i'` I can easily use `'-'.join(string)` and get the required output. But what if I want to do the same using regex? How would I do the same using regex?

I am asking because I'm learning to use regex and would like to know how to think in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `''.join(s)` doesn't care if `s` is made up of letters, spaces, or anything else, anything using `\w` or `\B` is going to be wrong for any string that isn't made up of purely "word characters".

You can easily adapt [nu11p01n73R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27457995/908494) to not rely on word characters:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=.)(?=.)', '-', s)
```

But [Avinash Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458055/908494) can't be; it relies on the magic of `\b` and `\B`, and there's no corresponding magic class for "character boundary" like there is for "word boundary".

Of course you could use just a normal capture group and a lookahead, instead of a lookbehind and a lookahead, which is probably a lot simpler:

```
re.sub(r'(.)(?=.)', r'\1-', s)
```

Answer (score 9):

A solution using look arounds will be

```
>>> import re
>>> str="abcdefghi"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\w)(?=\w)', '-', str)
'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i'
```

- `(?<=\w)` asserts that a letter is presceded by the postion
- `(?=\w)` asserts that a letter is followed by the postion

**OR**

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=.)(?=.)', '-', str)
'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i'
```

Comment: I did the same just with `.` however change `str` to `text` so you dont shadow the builtin.

Comment: `\w` gets consumed by the regex engine just like `.`. And you can use `.` in a lookahead just like `\w`.

Comment: @jamylak It took a while for me to understand what you wrote :(

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Do you mean about trying to use the `str()` function now that you used that variable name?

Answer (score 6):

Keep it Simple .....

```
>>> string = 'abcdefghi'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\B', '-', string)
'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i'
```

`\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character. But `\B` does the opposite of `\b`, that is it matches between two word characters and two non-word characters.

For more general case,

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=.)(?=.)', '-', string)
'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i'
```

I'll never let the `\B` to go. :)

```
>>> string = '(a)bc*d+e{f}gh[i]'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!^)(\B|\b)(?!$)', '-', string)
'(-a-)-b-c-*-d-+-e-{-f-}-g-h-[-i-]'
```

`(?<!^)` Negative lookbehind asserts that the match won't be preceded by start of the line anchor `^`. `(\B|\b)` matches word boundary or non-word boundary. `(?!$)` negative lookahead asserts that the match won't be followed by an end of the line anchor `$`.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't do the same thing as `'-'.join()` unless the whole string is made up of word characters.

Comment: @abarnert yep, you're right. This is specific. For more general case, it would be `(?<=.)(?=.)`